# 4 master server replicate to single server + 4 instances

Tags: mysql

MYSQL 5.X
i want to know how can we replicate 5 different master server to a single server having 5 DB instances in MYSQL replication. what are advantages and disadavntages.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to

- configure several MySQL servers on the same machine (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-servers.html)
- configure replication between a master and a slave (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-howto.html)

then you are good to go, I believe.

What is the purpose of this replication?

If for backup purposes only, then I do not see any disadvantage, especially if you run 5 separate instances of MySQL on the backup machine.
Just make sure your hardware is fast enough to deal with the combined activity of the 5 masters.

I don't see any other useful application for this setup.